# How to set where clause dynamically in GORM

Tags: sql, go, go-gorm

I will receive a `map[string][]string`. For each key in the map i want to add where clause like bellow.

```
inFilter := map[string][]string{"product_id": []string{"3", "69"}}
for key, value := range inFilter {
        filterQuerable = filterQuerable.Where("(?) IN (?)", key, value)
    }
```

it does not work. I tried bellow which also not works

```
filterQuerable = filterQuerable.Where("(?) IN (?)", "product_id", []string{"3", "69"})
```

Only bellow code works

```
filterQuerable = filterQuerable.Where("product_id IN (?)",  []string{"3", "69"})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see the problem now.  The `?` is for values, not column names.  If you can 100% trust the source of the inputs then a simple string replacement will work.  If you are are allowing data from users then you should be *very* careful and validated / sanitize the column names.

This should work.

```
inFilter := map[string][]string{"product_id": []string{"3", "69"}}
for key, value := range inFilter {
   filterQuerable = filterQuerable.Where(key + " IN (?)", value)
}
```

Comment: "Still not working."  Do you have an error you can produce?  And I see the problem now.

Answer (score 0):

For this kind of where clause you don't even need the for loop if you already have a map defined.

This should work:

```golang
inFilter := map[string][]string{"product_id": []string{"3", "69"}}
filterQuerable.Where(inFilter)
```

**Docs:** https://gorm.io/docs/query.html#Struct-amp-Map-Conditions

**Note:** This has the added benefit that you can't inject SQL since gorm parses the map into columns/values.